# how to add href with image source on html

Tags: html

How can I add href along with the image source? I do have alt tags but can't seem to figure out to hyperlink.

I tried including `<a>` tag but everything breaks.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                    <div class="img-box">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/G9vzNcc/5998900-sd.jpg" alt="APPLE IPAD" class="img-responsive img-fluid" alt="APPLE IPAD"   >  
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumb-content">
                        <h4>APPLE IPAD</h4>
                        <p></p>
                        <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BTS6C2J" rel="nofollow noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary">get it <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">buy now <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `href` is not an attribute of  `img` tag.

Comment: `<a href="link" class="class"> <img src="image source"> </a>` if i understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap your image `<img>` tag in an anchor `<a>` tag.